# Getting 'window.__contentLoaded is not a function' on Azure DevOps Server

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have Azure DevOps 2019 installed on a private Windows 2016 server. When I go to the Azure DevOps homepage using Chrome, http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/ I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.__contentLoaded is not a function
```

The code line where the error occurs. I removed alot of the css and js links for brevity.:

```
 <script data-description="contentInit">window.__moduleNamespaces = ["create-react-class","prop-types","react","react-dom","react-dom-factories","react-transition-group","tslib","VSS/Core","fetch","mousetrap","VSS/Platform","@microsoft/load-themed-styles","@uifabric","OfficeFabric","VSS/Fabric","VSSUI","VSS/Features/Frame","Tfs/Platform","TFS/Services","VSS/Features/Services","TFS/Views/SuiteMePage","TFS/GlobalBanner"];window.resourceLoadStrategy = 'stylesFirst';var previousResourceLoadCompletion = window.performance.now(); var resourceLoadTimes = {}; window.logResourceLoad = function (id) {var now = window.performance.now(); resourceLoadTimes[id] = { current: now, previous: previousResourceLoadCompletion }; previousResourceLoadCompletion = now; }; </script><script src="http://localhost:8080/_static/_ext/ms.vss-tfs-web/global-banner-content/ms.vss-tfs-web.global-banner-content.qFR9Djh9o8e2sd4x.min.js" data-contentlength="6124" data-clientid="ms.vss-tfs-web.global-banner-content/global-banner-content/ms.vss-tfs-web.global-banner-content.min.js" data-sourcecontribution="ms.vss-tfs-web.global-banner-content" data-loadingcontent="true"></script><script data-description="logResourceLoad">window.logResourceLoad('ms.vss-tfs-web.global-banner-content/global-banner-content/ms.vss-tfs-web.global-banner-content.min.js');</script><script data-description="fireLoadEvents">var contentElements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-loadingcontent=true]"); for (var i=0; i<contentElements.length; i++) { var loadTimes = resourceLoadTimes[contentElements[i].getAttribute('data-clientid')]; window.__contentLoaded(contentElements[i], true, loadTimes && loadTimes.current, loadTimes && loadTimes.previous); }</script>
```

The above 'window.contentLoaded is not a function' error causes the min css and js files to have 404 not found status.

I've tried clearing my cookies in Chrome, emptying my internet cache with no success. I've even tried doing a repair install of Azure DevOps Server and still get the error.

I think the error might have to do with the version of Java installed on the server. The error seemed to start happening when I installed a different version of Java. Azul Zulu Java 8 was installed and I installed Azul Zulu Java 11. I updated JAVA_HOME and the system path.

I'm completely stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I can't determine the cause of the problem. It may be the configuration of sever. You can try to re-install and configure Azure Devops Server. Then check if this problem can be solved.

Comment: @Kevin Lu-MSFT Is there a way to check what version of Java Azure DevOps Server is using?

Comment: From this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/updates-to-java-requirements-for-tfs-search/),  Azure Devops Server uses the `Azul Zulu OpenJDK 8 community `version by default.

Comment: I figured out how to update the version of Java for Azure DevOps Server. Unfortunately the error is still there.

Comment: This problem may be related to the configuration of the azure devops server itself. If possible , you could try to re-install the Azure Devops Server again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the error by installing the latest update for Azure DevOps Server 2019 and restored the associated database.